# Oauth error missing_shopify_permission: read_all_orders

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

When i mentioned scope read_all_orders . I faced the following error while installation

Oauth error missing_shopify_permission: read_all_orders

Without read_all_orders scope App install perfectly.

I dont know what happens exactly i am trying both new created store and 2 month old store

My scopes :- 'read_products', 'read_orders', 'read_customers', 'write_orders', 'read_price_rules', 'write_price_rules',    'read_all_orders'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per [Shopify documentation](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/getting-started/authentication/oauth/scopes)

> **read_all_orders**
>
> Grants access to all orders rather than the default window of 60 days
>   worth of orders. This OAuth scope is used in conjunction with
>   read_orders, or write_orders. You need to request this scope from your
>   Partner Dashboard before adding it to your app.

To do so

> **read_all_orders access:**
>
> From your app's overview page, click App setup.
>
> In the Orders section, click Request access to all orders.
>
> Provide a description about why you are applying for access.
>
> Click Request access.